# OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow-serving

I'm making a model for binary sentiment analysis, I already made the pre-processing and the model works well. I am trying to create an initial Input Layer and later a Lambda layer, this in order to have inputs when I save my model and upload it to Docker to get predictions by Tensorflow Serving.

Create a function for pre-processing the model input:

```
@tf.function
def serving(input_serving: tf.string)-> tf.Tensor:
    X = []
    sentences = list(input_serving)
    for sen in sentences:
      X.append(preprocess_text(sen))
    X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([input_serving])
    X = pad_sequences(X, padding='post', maxlen=100)
    rtn = tf.convert_to_tensor(X)
    return rtn
```

And this is the structure of my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(),dtype="string"))
model.add(Lambda(serving))
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=100 , trainable=False)
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
```

Trying to compile the model gives this error:
**OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.**

What should I modify to fix this? Or some other way to be able to add these inputs for the predictions?

Thanks.